# Having an issue with JavaScript Toggle function

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with my toggleElement function, it will not change the style to block and then none. I don't know if I coded the function wrong or if I'm not calling it correctly.

Any feedback would be great!!

Thanks

```
    <link href="chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js" ></script> 
<title>Chat Room | BetterGamerzUnited</title>
<script>
function toggleElement(x){
  var x = document.getElementById(x);
  if(x.style.display == 'block'){
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
  <?php include $path . '/includes/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="colorpickerB" style='display:none;'>
      <div id="colorpicker">
        <img src="/members/chat/palette.png" id="palette" alt="Color Palette" border="1"/>
        <br />
        <input id="color" type="hidden" readonly="true" value="#000000" />
      </div>    
    </div>
    <table id="content">
      <tr id="chat-top">
        <td>
          <div id="scroll">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="chat-btm">
        <td colspan="2">
          <div id="items">
            <input type="text" class="" id="messageBox" placeholder="Enter your message here" maxlength="2000" size="30" />
          </div>
          <div id="color">
            <button type="button" id="sampleText" class="chat-btn" onclick="toggleElement(colorpickerB);">
              Color
            </button>
          </div>          
          <input type="hidden" class="" id="userName" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>" maxlength="20"/>
          <input type="button" class="chat-btn" value="Send" id="send" />
          <?php
          if ($user_ok === true) {
              if (($log_userlevel == '7') || ($log_userlevel == '8')) {
                echo '<input type="button" class="chat-btn" value="Delete All" id="delete" />';
              }
            }
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are passing a DOM element to `getElementById`, but you have to pass a string. `toggleElement(colorpickerB)` should be `toggleElement('colorpickerB')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have ever defined `colorpickerB` before calling `toggleElement(colorpickerB);`. Perhaps you meant to pass in the string `'colorpickerB'` instead of an identifier:

```
toggleElement('colorpickerB');
```

Comment: Thank you its just been along day, I have looked at to much js